# Php page not found

Tags: php

I have an index.php and some pages like
Index.php/dashboard.php etc. I noticed that if I type by mistake index.php/d I do not get an error 
For object/page not found but I see the index page without any bootstrap/css. How can I tell php to display an page not found for these 
Type mistaken url examples?

Comment: Looking at your code in line 12 ... no wait. You should really post the code for your index.php (if that is the one handling all the pages). Make a whitelist of pages that are allowed, if you hit one that isn't whitelisted, throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create .htaccess file in root folder and add following code :**

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://siteurl.com/404.php
```

**Create 404.php in root folder**

```
<?php
// Add your 404 page error page content or layout
echo "This page is not found. Please enter valid URL";    
?>
```

**Let's Check its working**

http://siteurl.com/mypage.php

// considering this page is not existing you should get 404 page

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the .htaccess file was in the root folder of the 
project and not the htdocs folder